# How to run pre-push git hook only when files in a subfolder have changed since the last push?

Tags: git

I have a monorepo that has a C# backend with a react frontend. The frontend is in a subfolder and I'm trying to setup a git hook specifically for the react client. I've installed husky, which handles the git hooks, and I've created a pre-push hook which runs every time I try to push my latest commits.

However, I only want that pre-push hook to run if there are commits that contains changes from the frontend. The initial way I've attempted doing this is having the script run a `git show` command to output some filenames, and if matched to the file path of our react client, to run the command I want ran pre-push:

```
if git show --name-only -r --stat --oneline HEAD^^..HEAD | grep -q 'ReactClient/'; then
  npm run verify
fi
```

The problem is that this only checks the last 2 commits, I believe. I need to check the files changed in ALL commits for the current branch that have changed since the last time I pushed to the remote repo. How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the git command slightly:

```
currentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD..origin/$currentBranch | grep -q 'client/'; then
  cd client
  npm run verify
fi
```